# EJB, rmi port in WebSphere

Tags: ejb, websphere

I was wondering where I can control the ejb/rmi port in WebSphere.
I have noticed it doens't appear in the "ports" section in the Server Definitions in websphere. Something tells me it is the nodeAgent that controls this rmi port.

How may I control this?
Am I right in my assumption?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this article for information on this space. It is pretty old but i believe a lot of this is still true for the newer versions of WAS

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0310_alcott/alcott.html

HTH

Manglu

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap Port (BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS) is used for rmi connections In IBMwebsphere.2809 is the default port.
http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc%2Finfo%2Fiseriesnd%2Fae%2Frmig_portnumber.html